# callbackUrl not working on production with nextauth google provider

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, vercel, next-auth, next.js13

In my use case, not sensitive information is generated before the user signs up, I want to be able to use oauth and tie this information after the signup flow.

When I use the signIn function with the google provider, I want to pass data through search parameters in the callbackUrl, I am able to get it on localhost, but when I deploy on Vercel it does not work, the google provider simply redirects to my home page.

### on my custom sign in

```js
...
signIn('google', {
    callbackUrl: MY_ROUTES.linkNewUser.path + "?someData=12345",
});
...
```

### on the "link-new-user" api route

```js
...
const someData = searchParams.someData;
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Google docs for Oauth](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#uri-validation) it is not possible to use a fragment (search parameters) in the redirect_uri.

Since it is more tolerant with urls matching "localhost", it will work in a dev environment but not on production.

To be able to achieve my goal I simply saved a cookie before the signup flow, and retrieved it afterwards. There are many strategies to achieve this goal, and to set and get cookies, I won't cover them here.

Comment: Just to clarify — in the example, you're using the query string, not fragment. The fragment is the part after the `#`.

Comment: @MichalTrojanowski Even it it's not mentionned in the Google docs, it is specified in the RFC 3986 specs : https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-3.5


"A fragment identifier component is indicated by the presence of a
   number sign ("#") character and terminated by the end of the URI.

      fragment    = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
"

Answer (score 0):

OAuth uses a `state` parameter. You can call the authorization endpoint with the `state` query parameter and the authorization server should send the parameter back in the redirect URL. Not sure if Google supports that properly, however, as their implementation of OAuth does not always conform to the standard.

Still, if there's a lot of data you want to keep it's usually better to save it in a cookie or `localStorage`.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughtful insight @Michal, I cannot accept it as the problem is about the callbarkUrl not working in a production environment, not how to transfer data in another way.